# Centering an image with changemargin command

Tags: graphics

I'm using `changemargin` package for the first page of my thesis, but

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}    
\usepackage[italian]{babel}             
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage{ragged2e}               
\usepackage{amsmath}                    
\usepackage{amssymb}            

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
%Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % cancella tutti i campi
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
 \begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
 }%
\item[]}{\end{list}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape} % Per la pagina di grafici
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norma}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\justifying                                     

\date{28 Luglio 2014}
\author{Gabriele Mazza}
\title{}

\begin{document}


\begin{changemargin}{-1.3cm}{-3cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{\textsc{Politecnico di Milano}}\\
\vspace{5mm}
\large{\textsc{Scuola di Ingegneria Industriale e dell'Informazione}}\\
\vspace{3mm}
\large{\textsc{Corso di Studi in Ingegneria Matematica}}\\
\vspace{8mm}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=35mm]{Immagini/Logo.png}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\vspace{1mm}
\begin{center}
\large{\textsc{Tesi di Laurea Magistrale}}
\end{center}
\vspace{20mm}

\begin{center}
\begin{huge}
\textsc{Regressione con regolarizzazioni differenziali per dati spazio-temporali, con applicazione all'analisi della produzione di rifiuti urbani nella provincia di Venezia}
\end{huge}
\end{center}
\vspace{20mm}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{l l }
\textsc{Relatore}:    & \textsc{Prof. Laura Maria SANGALLI} \\
\textsc{Correlatore}: & \textsc{Dott. Ing. Mara Sabina BERNARDI}
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\vspace{9mm}
\begin{flushright}
\textsc{Tesi di Laurea di:} \\ 
\textsc{Gabriele MAZZA} \\
\textsc{Matr. 798794}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{12mm}
\begin{center}
{\large{\textsc{Anno Accademico 2013/2014}}}
\end{center}
\end{changemargin}
\end{document}
```

but the image isn't central like the test. How can I fix it? (you can find Logo.png here:http://www.google.it/imgres?imgurl=http://www.grep.it/downloads/Loghi/logo-polimi.png&imgrefurl=http://www.grep.it/downloads.php&h=720&w=720&tbnid=e8AIT7oulNxcfM:&zoom=1&q=logo+polimi+tesi&docid=bCPVvarMMx0hTM&ei=JnMZVZfEO4KxUbXugZAF&tbm=isch&ved=0CCEQMygBMAE )

Comment: `\begin{center}\huge\scshape Long title of your thesis\end{center}` and you'll not suffer from strange interline in the title.

Comment: Wow, thanks! this was the second problem of the page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logo is *not* a float, remove the figure environment. With a simple

```
\begin{center}%
    \includegraphics[width=35mm]{Immagini/Logo.png}%
\end{center}
```

instead of:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=35mm]{Immagini/Logo.png}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

you get this:

[image]